# gpg --export-secret-keys

Tags: gnupg

Whenever I decrypt a file with gpg, I get asked for my passphrase. E. g.

```
gpg -d File.gpg
```

However I can export my private key without getting asked for my passphrase:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor --output SecretKeysFile.asc
```

Is the exported private key in the generated file SecretKeysFile.asc still encrypted with my passphrase? Or will anybody who has access to this file be able to decrypt encrypted files?

Answer (score 10):

Anyone who imports your secret keys will need to enter the appropriate passphrases to use them, just as you do now. You could test this by creating a new user and importing the `SecretKeysFile.asc` file, etc.